# less lazy looking way to add mulitple things to database mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answers.Answer,
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answers.Answer,
         new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answers.Answer, "",
        new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

and a controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AId,QId,Answer")] Answers answers)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
var answerarr = answers.Answer.Split(';');
            foreach (String a in answerarr)
            {
                answers.QId = QIda;
                answers.Answer = a;
                db.Answers.Add(answers);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
//some code
```

and the application works perfectly fine. 
However i want to add multiple answers to the databse at the same time without having to click on submit every time

the current workaround is just using split but thats just lazy and ugly.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Comment: you can use list for multiple value insert but for that you need to passed multiple answers from your view as well.

Comment: The have multiple textboxes in your view to add multiple answers (and dynamically add then using javascript as required)